# cameraman image read as color and grayscale in matlab and octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I got a cameraman image from internet. I tried to run the following command in octave

```
 I=imread('original_cameraman.jpg');
 original = im2double(rgb2gray((I)));
```

It showed the following error:

error: rgb2gray: the input must either be an RGB image or a colormap

I tried the same code in matlab and it worked correctly. Matlab read the image as color while octave read it as grayscale. What is the reason? How can I run the code correctly in octave?

Cameraman image which I used is given below:  [image]

Answer (score 2):

Your embedded image already is grayscale:

```
$ gm identify -verbose original_cameraman.jpg.jpg
Format: JPEG (Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format)
  Geometry: 512x512
  Class: DirectClass
  Type: grayscale
  Depth: 8 bits-per-pixel component
  Channel Depths:
    Gray:     8 bits
  Channel Statistics:
    Gray:
      Minimum:                     0.00 (0.0000)
      Maximum:                 65535.00 (1.0000)
      Mean:                    30296.32 (0.4623)
      Standard Deviation:      15987.34 (0.2440)
```

so no need to call `rgb2gray`

Comment: Please try it using matlab. In matlab rgb2gray works for this image

Comment: And what does `rgb2gray` in matlab do? Just return the input as output? So what is your problem here? Taht Octave gives you an error if you feed a grayscale image as input and Matlab just ignores it?

Comment: But matlab shows 'I' as 512*512*3 matrix where as octave shows it as 512*512. Pardon me if I am asking some foolishness. But to my knowledge 512*512*3 implies that 'I' is a color image

Comment: @elantra, yes, MxNx3 is a color image. The color can be gray, but its a color image

Comment: Okay, then it's the underlying graphics magick. If the gm library detects a grayscale image then it returns a MxN matrix, no matter if it's representation is stored as RGB image

Comment: So can you please suggest a solution for me to run this program correctly without any errors(I need to use rgb2gray function too) in octave

Comment: @elantra why? What is your use-case? Is this part of a script you can't touch? Are you trying to make the same code run on both matlab and octave? Is there a guy who really loves `rgb2gray` in the room? :p  (give all the relevant information in the question to get the right answer, and avoid you having to keep expanding the question and frustrating people trying to answer it!)

Comment: @Tasos Papastylianou Ya I am trying to make the same code run on both matlab and octave

Comment: @elantra in general, when you have access to the code, you can use `isOctave` [from here](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/How-to-Distinguish-Between-Octave-and-Matlab.html#How-to-Distinguish-Between-Octave-and-Matlab) in an `if / else` block to handle matlab and octave differently. However, in this case, you could simply check `if size(I,3) == 3` before calling `rgb2gray`.

Comment: As a side note, should this be filed as a comparability bug?